# Create PyPi package from Project

Tags: python, pip, open-source, pypi

I have made an Open Source AI Coding Assistant in python: https://github.com/00-Python/AI-Debug

I am new to making PyPi Packages  to be able to install my project with pip.

Im not sure where to start, can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python.org has exactly the documentation you're looking for: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

In sum, you'll go through roughly the following steps:

1. Adjust your directory structure (as needed) to create a `src` dir for the code you want in the package (leaving out extra files not needed in an install, e.g. automated tests)
2. Create a `pyproject.toml` file that defines metadata and build system info for your package
3. Build the package
4. Use `twine` to upload the package to pypi (you'll need to create a pypi account if you haven't already)